# How to pair two tuples in python?

Tags: python

I need to build a function that takes in 2 tuples, and pairs them to all the pairs possible.

for example i need to take to tuples:

```
first_tuple = (1, 2)
second_tuple = (4, 5)
```

and the result need to be:

```
((1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 5), (5, 2))
```

Comment: Please take out some time in reading existing answers in the linked duplicate and try applying it to your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first start by creating the initial pairing using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and then use that pairing to create another pairing where the tuple elements are swapped

```
from itertools import product
first_tuple = (1, 2)
second_tuple = (4, 5)

#First pairing
prod_1 = list(product(first_tuple, second_tuple))

#Pairing with swapped positions of tuple
prod_2 = [(t[1], t[0]) for t in prod_1]

#Final output
res = prod_1 + prod_2
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 1), (5, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), the idea is to take all posible product orderings and since the tuples have size 2 you just need to flip them:

```
>>> from itertools import product, chain
>>> first_tuple = (1, 2)
>>> second_tuple = (4, 5)
>>> half = list(product(first_tuple, second_tuple))
>>> half
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
>>> list(chain(half, map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), half)))
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 1), (5, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
```

For an arbitrary tuple size you can use (@Aran-Fei idea):

```
[perm for tup in half for perm in itertools.permutations(tup)]
```

Comment: The last line can be changed to `[perm for tup in half for perm in itertools.permutations(tup)]` if you want to support an arbitrary number of input tuples instead of just two.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain,product

first_tuple = (1, 2)
second_tuple = (4, 5)

combined = list(chain(*[[(f,s),(s,f)] for f in first_tuple for s in second_tuple]))
print (combined)
```

output:

```
[(1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 5), (5, 2)]
```

.

> **itertools.product()**
>
> This tool computes the cartesian product of input iterables.  It is
>   equivalent to nested for-loops.  For example, product(A, B) returns
>   the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

To get first part of desired list is:

```
list(product(first_tuple, second_tuple)) # (1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1)
```

for the second part is enough to reverse:

```
list(product(second_tuple, first_tuple)) # (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 5), (5, 2)
```

.

```
combined1 = list(product(first_tuple, second_tuple)) + list(product(second_tuple, first_tuple))
print (combined1)
```

output:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (5, 2)]
```